# Centura Team Developer (previously Gupta Team Developer)

Tags: opentext, sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper, centura, unify

This question might not be very constructive but my reason for asking this question here is to know the view of fellow TD developers about the career scope of this niche technology in India.

I have been working with this technology from the last 4 years. Started off with Gupta Team Developers (SqlWindows 3.0 PTF4) and currently working in Centura Team Developer 6.3.1.

What are the career opportunities for a CTD developer in India?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Centura' used to be the generic term used for Gupta SQLWindows / TeamDeveloper and associated toolset. Actually,  Centura only released one version of the toolset - v1.5. The toolset is now owned and developed by OpenText ( and is commonly referred to as Gupta ) and the latest release is v7.1 - which is native 64bit , UNICODE and .Net enabled.  Go here to see the OpenText Gupta Product Overview :  https://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-team-developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , I suggest you update your terminology. You'll get no-where calling it 'CTD' or 'Centura'.  There is no such thing as Centura TeamDeveloper or CTD any more, least of all  v6.3 .   CTD became 'GTD' Gupta TeamDeveloper again from v3 onwards , and more recently since v7 , it became
'OpenText Gupta TeamDeveloper'.
Suggest you join the Gupta User Group [Click here](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/144210) or Tech Forum [Click Here](http://tdforum.daverabelink.net/index.php)for this type of non-tech question .

Update: **As of 28 August 2023** and as a further answer to:

> 'What are the career opportunities for a CTD developer in India?'

There now seems to be many, many Gupta ( or 'Centura' as you call it ) skills advertised in India - particularly on LinkedIn.